# Security proof for PRNG

Tags: random-number-generator

Could you help to find an example of where the next kind of proof is performed, please?
"if we can distinguish the randomly generated bits of a PRNG from a random sequence, then we can distinguish the underlying block cipher/permutation from a random permutation"

Comment: A construction where you would see this kind of proof summary is counter mode with a fixed start using the random input as the key, i.e. $G(x)=E_x(0)\|E_x(1)\|E_x(2)\|E_x(3)\|\ldots$